# There is no app.xaml in MonoGame Windows Store project in VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, monogame

I need an Application object of my MonoGame project (Visual Studio Pro 2012) to install exception handler, but I can't find App.xaml and corresponding App.xaml.cs, although have no problems with it in Windows Phone 8 Monogame application.
Tried to use Application.Current (like in WP) but get Unrecoverable Exception. Discouraged.

If I create an empty xaml app for Windows Store I see App.xaml.
Please tell me what's the mistery in monogame app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what's going on. When create Monogame app for Windows Store I should use "Monogame Windows Store (XAML)" template instead of "Monogame Windows Store".